# How to find easily the source of an android class

Tags: android, android-source

I know I can access android source code from https://android.googlesource.com, but it's hard to select the right git repo if I only know the package and the name of an android class.

Isn't there a way to locate a file in https://android.googlesource.com?

Comment: If you're working with Eclipse, see the answer for question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most things you'll want to see can be found under the [`frameworks/base`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/) repo.
This includes pretty much all the public and private API classes that make up the Android Java framework.

If you want to be able to browse the source from within Eclipse, you can follow this guide: http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html

Finally, the [Android SDK Reference Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-reference-sea/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin) extension for Chrome lets you browse the public API by typing `ad` into the URL bar, and it adds a convenient "view source" link to each Javadoc page.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion today the best way to look into android sources is the github repository :

https://github.com/android/

Public java classes can be found here https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android

Internal package is here https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/com/android/internal

Resources are here https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res

Support library https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support

Answer (score 2):

Since 2011 the source code can be downloaded with the SDK Manager (Window > Android SDK Manager)

- Install package "Sources for Android SDK"
- Open Properties of android.jar, which you can find in the package explorer below the Android library
- In "Java Source Attachment", select android/sdk/sources as external folder

**Edit:** Eclipse seems to regularly scan the external folder for updates. If this annoys you, you can zip the folder into a .jar and then tell Eclipse to look in that jar for the sources. Eclipse will then no longer scan for changes.

Comment: Thanks. Over an hour of searching led me here and this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue raised against Android project](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=979) for a single `.jar` file containing the Java sources.

The issue has been declined but the comments are a good source of methods to access the source in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

also, this is a very good [tutorial](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/) on how to get the source in eclipse, without having to mess with any of the repos or anything, it includes zip files of the the source (which might be out of date)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any Android class through https://cs.android.com easily.