# Source not found Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

am facing a problem in Eclipse android development tool

```
Source not found
EDIT SOURCE LOOKUP PATH
```

while i debug code in class Instrumentation.class at line
@param info ActivityInfo from the manifest

above error is raised.

can any one guide me how to resolve this issue?? i am new to android development..

Comment: andreas could you please elebrate your answer i am new to java and dont understand these terms... where to locate what..

Comment: check if your activity is defined in the android manifest file

Comment: If you're working with Eclipse, see the answer for question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sources of the Android API are not included in the SDK download.  So when the debugging goes to an Android class Eclipse will raise an error.

Have a look at [this questions for instructions on how to add the source to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964620/how-to-find-easily-the-source-of-an-android-class/1965543#1965543).

Comment: i have seen this example many times.. but the problem is i am doing development in windows vista and this tutorial leads to android site which tells windows is not supported so in order to download source code only mac and linux are supported :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your eclipse build path if the folder, that contains you source code is really on the defined build path.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error. It was due to variable used to change the app background color. I had created a varibale in string.xml as mycolor = "#FF3344" and had added it as background of Linerar Layout. It seems more of coding error.

Answer (score 0):

If an activity want any special feature, then it should be registered on the `manifestfile` for permission to handle that feature. If you are not registering it in manifestfile, then the

> source not found
>
> EDIT SOURCE LOOKUP PATH

would occur when you are on debugging mode.

I would recommend especially for focus on "uses-permission" tag in manifestfile

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in wrong coding.
Check the AndroidManifest.xml file.