# Source not found error in "Android"

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Source not found Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071614/source-not-found-android)

While executing my android application I am getting source not found message.Because of this error message I am not getting the proper output.Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Hey, post your some code or Logcat message which will be more useful to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean/rebuild in eclipse and install it on the phone again. (I had that problem recently)
I had to uninstall the application on my phone too.

Answer (score 0):

if it is at runtime (like loading a raw file to your app) then your surely got a typo in your address (happend to me with raw xml files and fonts).

if this is in your IDE/while coding then your java build is out of sync.
several reasons can cause this (you edited a files outside of eclipses, added files to the directory without passing through eclipse...)

since I use a lot of personal C libs I got in the habit each time I cahnge anything to do:

- on the project root folder in the package explorer: (with eclipse) the combination ctrl+shift+o/cmd+shift+o(mac): reloads all files.
- F5 to refresh the project
- project->clean, to fully rebuild all the project

(its an overkill to redo everything each time but with those 3 your should be able to solve all ressource related issues).

one warning: DO NOT clean your project if one of your ressources has an invalid name!!!:
example:
My-Super-Bitmap123(2).jpg has invalide caracters

if you clean it will remove the gen R file
try to rebuild it from the ressources, fail because it can't create 
public final static My-Super-Bitmap123(2) = 39483291842093; //content of the R file

and then since your R file doesn't exists the clean operation will remove all

```
import com.myapp.R
```

and then your project won't build until you manually fixe all your imports and R.drawable.--- calls (which is a huge pain :P)

Hope it helps