# Source not found error after HttpClient.execute()

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. I have the following class for downloading some data in JSON format. I keep getting a Source not found error on the
     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
line... I'm sure this must be a simple fix... Here is the class code...

```
 package com.example.tankandroid;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

}
```

Comment: What `url` are you using?

Comment: "http://www.simonsayssolutions.co.uk/index.php"

Comment: This Source not found error is really misleading, can you make sure that's what is being caught as the exception?

Comment: The URL looks fine and it returns nicely formatted JSON. Could you please have a look at my answer and provide some more information regarding when and where your get the "Source not found" message

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in onCreate method

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache HttpCore and HttpClient libraries. Put these two libraries into your lib folder, its automatically add these into your build path.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this situation may be missing internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file. Adding this line in manifest will fix the issue.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide some more information I think. Where do you get the "Source not found" error? Is it an Eclipse error that prevents you from compiling. Is it during compilation? Is it a runtime error? Could this be a possible duplicate of: [Source not found Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071614/source-not-found-android) ?

Question: Why are you doing an HTTP POST if you don't intend to add any POST data? A GET seems more appropriate.

And since you also ask "I'm sure this must be a simple fix" then yes, it is. I'd really suggest that you rip out your HTTP code and switch to [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). It's super easy to work with and very well suited for getting an HTTP response and parsing it. Example:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
rp.put("some_param", "some value");
rp.put("another_param", "some other value");
client.post("http://www.simonsayssolutions.co.uk/index.php", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public final void onSuccess(String response) {
        // handle your response and parse JSON here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
        // something went wrong
    }               
});
```

or GET:

```
client.get("http://www.simonsayssolutions.co.uk/index.php", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
...
}
```

And finally if you want to simplify JSON parsing have a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Especially if you want to parse JSON data to Java objects and vice versa.