# Insert some rows into the table only once when the DataBase is created

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to insert 2 rows into a table, when the DataBase is created for the first time .

Here is my code:

```
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_TABLE2);

         _db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+DATABASE_TABLE_2+" VALUES('com.android.music',1);");
         _db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+DATABASE_TABLE_2+" VALUES('com.android.clender',1);");

    }
```

Please let me know if i am wrong . Is there any other way of doing it.

Comment: what's the error that you are getting??

Comment: source not found , i am fetching the records putting it into an array.

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071614/source-not-found-android

Comment: Can you post what is in `DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_TABLE2`?