# Android Eclipse Source Not Found Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I am very new to android programming, and I ran into a problem with Eclipse having a source not found error while debugging one of my applications. The error looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrPDn.png).

From what I looked up already on this site, it seemed that people went to [this](http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/) site and installed new software within eclipse. However, that didn't change anything when I tried. Still got the error.

Other posts that I read involved installing the Sources for Android in the SDK manager. I re-installed and installed that again, and it still didn't change anything.

Other solutions that I read about involved re-installing the Android SDK libraries, which I tried with no avail.

The code that breaks is this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);

    listview_items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_Items);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listview_items.setAdapter(itemsAdapter); // It always breaks on this line

    items.add("First Item");
    items.add("Second Item");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

If someone could let me know what happened that would be great!

Comment: which source do you want?

Comment: It seems that there is just a general Android sources that allows you to debug android classes that are part of the Android framework. Something like that was discussed  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071614/source-not-found-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attaching Java Source to Android projects in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182904/attaching-java-source-to-android-projects-in-eclipse)