# How to attach source to android.jar

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android.  I am working in the Windows OS with the Eclipse IDE. My simple application has a spinner that populates a list from database column. When I click on the spinner Class, the file Editor says that source not found and the android.jar has no source attachment.

I downloaded the source code and placed it in this location:

`android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8`

Then, I attached this source by these steps:

right click the project => build path=> configure build path=> libraries => source attachment => give the path of the source code downloaded.

But, I didn't get any solution for my debug. Again, when clicking on the spinner it opens the debug that android.jar has no source attachment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To attach source code for android.jar, you may follow the tutorial at the link below: 
http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/
Make sure to choose the correct platform version.

If you meet difficutly with spinner, try to get the sample code and see how it works: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html

Good luck. :)

## Update

This answer is quite out of date, please consider other answers.

Comment: It would be good if you post at least a summary of the link on here. If that link goes down for any reason, we've lost the entire answer.

Comment: @Blowski if the link goes down, then we cannot get the jar files, so my summary will be not useful anymore... :)              @Santhosh plz mark the answer as accepted, so the others can find this easier.

Comment: You're really going to beg for upvotes on an admittedly wrong answer?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek thanks for downing votes, just want to give others another option. Deleted as your wish, hopefully make you happy.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek "Cannot remove accepted answer", removed "BEGGING" sentence. olo

Comment: @doreamon I know, I can't believe what a jerk I am, downvoting a completely wrong answer. I hope downvoting a bunch of my actually correct answers made you feel better

Comment: The FIRST LINK  link in the answer above is no longer in existance. "404. file not found."

Answer (score 90):

This is now really easy!

Go to Window->Android SDK Manager and install "Sources for Android SDK".

Now try to control-click some Android identify, you will get the usual "no source attached" page. Click "Attach Source" and get the option to select an external folder.

Now browse to `/home/me/android-sdks/sources/android-16` (or wherever your SDK is installed; this is the default), and hit ok.

It should think for a moment and then display the source! Yeay!

Comment: This only included API's 14-16 for me. Otherwise to me the preferrable way, thanks!

Comment: They did not add any "Sources for Android SDK" in the SDK manager until API 14. Every version after that has included that option so far. Most developers should be able to increase the API they target (not minSDK) and use the newest API source in Eclipse.

Comment: If this doesn't work, see fsbmain's answer, which ended up working for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me:  The attach source dialog expects to find a .zip or .jar file, and won't allow "hitting ok" on just the directory. This is with ADT v21, Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Regarding Joe's comment:  " The attach source dialog expects to find a .zip or .jar file, and won't allow "hitting ok" on just the directory.".... Actually, you CAN get around that by clickking the EXTERNAL FOLDER button to the right of the PATH field.   By default the External Location Path is set to EXTERNAL FILE.      (inside the SOURCE ATTACHMENT CONFIGURATION window).

Comment: continuation from my comment above:  Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem for me, but at first it seemed it did because it accepted the FOLDER selection.  Reading all the other comments on this page, tho I have not tried everything, It would seem the consensus is that "android.jar" should be inside the SOURCES/ANDROID-XX folder.  It is not there, and I have installed all the source files for my targeted build and every other possible build availalbe in the SDK (VIA THE SDK MANAGER).   So still hunting for the solution.

Answer (score 85):

Unless you need older API sources, you are probably better served by Timmmm's answer. If you do need sources older than 14, read on...

In Eclipse simply go to

> Help -> Install New Software

then add update site

> http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/

and go through the motions to install it.

This will happily provide sources for all installed API versions and works very well for me. 
Some more documentation is here

> http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/

look for the heading **Android Sources**

Comment: The method mention in thomanski's answer is the only way for me. I'm on Windows XP, Eclipse 3.7
Sorry to put this as an answer, I can't add comment yet.

Comment: I ran the install, and don't have source.  Is there more to do?  The linked document is not helpful to me; I need step-by-step.

Comment: @CarlManaster No, there is not more to do. If you've added the update site and restarted eclipse you should have access to the sources. As Dean pointed out though, not all version's sources are included. Are you perhaps using honeycomb?

Comment: Very good. Unfortunately there doesn't seem a way to only select some android versions, you have to download the source for all versions.

Comment: worked for me as well. Also I wish I could select a particular android version.

Comment: The SDK manager now has options to download the Android source code. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect after you install it. No wait, I worked it out, see answer below.

Comment: Didn't work for me, and I do need sources less than API 14 I believe, since I'm targeting 11.

Answer (score 14):

If adding folder `android-sdks/sources/android-17` as external source doesn't work (as in my case) you can try to create folder `android-sdks/platforms/android-17/sources/android-17` copy sources to it and restart eclipse (I have eclipse Juno Service Release 1). Only this way works for me.

Steps to do this for android-17:

1. Go to the `adroid-sdk` install folder, for me it's `d:\ws\android-sdks\`
2. Copy `android-17` sources folder from `android-sdks\sources\android-17\` to the `android-sdks\platforms\android-17\sources\` (your have to create folder `sources` here manually) folder so the final path to the sources must be the: `android-sdks\platforms\android-17\sources\android-17\`
3. restart the eclipse, it must automatically attach sources for android-17

UPD: the same solution with `symlinks`:

**Windows Vista+** (thanks @saleemrashid1 for mentioning `mklink` in comments):

```
1. cd platforms\android-17
2. mklink /D "sources\android-17" "..\..\..\sources\android-17"
```

**For Unix-base OSes** (@Joe comment):

it works fine to create the directory and symlink "sources/android-XX"
to "../../../sources/android-XX":

```
mkdir platforms/android-19/sources && 
ln -s ../../../sources/android-19 platforms/android-19/sources/android-19.
```

Comment: worked for me as well. I was also facimg similar problem as yours. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you describe it step by step, please? I'm trying this but doesn't help.

Comment: I've added steps to my answer

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks! Out of curiosity, why can't the original source folder be used for android-17?

Comment: I don't know, my colleague with the same with me system configuration has the @Timmmm solution worked, but it doesn't works for me by some reasons I didn't managed to detect.

Comment: This worked for me also.  Note: you do not have to copy (`cp -R`) the sources, it works fine to create the directory and symlink "sources/android-XX" to "../../../sources/android-XX":  `mkdir platforms/android-19/sources && ln -s ../../../sources/android-19 platforms/android-19/sources/android-19`.  This of course assumes you are on a platform and filesystem that supports symbolic links (Mac OS X and Linux -- Windows does not)

Comment: `mklink.exe` is the `ln`-ish command of Windows Vista and up.

Comment: @Joe and saleemrashid1 Thanks for tips, I included them to the answer

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me follows the answer found in Murach's Android Programming. I got stuck trying to debug and tried to work it out for about 3 hours before turning to the next page (literally) where it said "Sometimes Eclipse will display a source not found message because...." (-headdesk-)

My solution was to turn on Step Filtering and add the packages that I wanted to skip when debugging. Evidently, Eclipse sometimes steps through all the source code libraries, when all you want is for it to step through your code. You can bypass this by adding the packages you want to skip to the filter. According to Murach, you kinda just do it by trial and error, starting with selecting all packages and adding them. As you continue with debugging you might find you need to add more packages to the filter.

Specific steps:
1. Turn on step filtering; click the button in the toolbar on the top that looks like this: http://i57.tinypic.com/x3iccp.png
2. Go to Window-->Preferences, then in the Preferences dialog, select Java-->Debug-->Step Filtering
3. Select all packages.
4. To add additional filters, click "Add Filter", type the name of the package with a .* at the end, and click OK. Murach recommends adding these common  packages to begin:
--android.*
--com.android.*
--com.google.*
--dalvik.*
--libcore.*
--org.apache.*
So to add one of these packages, click "Add Filter", type "android.*", and click OK. I ended up having all of the following packages on my Step Filter Preferences.

android.*, android.app.*, com.android.*, com.google.*, com.ibm.*, com.sun.*, dalvik.*, java.*, javax.*, jrockit.*, libcore.*, org.apache.*, org.omg.*, sun.*, sunw.*, ((and this last one is a class, not a package)) java.lang.ClassLoader

I had "Use Step Filters" checked at the top of the dialog box, and "Step through filters" checked at the bottom. Click "Apply", then "OK" to close the dialog. It should work.

Good luck!

Comment: I found this helpful.  I also added:    --com.paypal.* --com.samsung.android.* and I am still finding more to add.  Once I added all the ones that Kate used, and the 2 above, I am getting along farther into the process before I hit the SOURCE NOT FOUND.  ~~ Interesting Point ~~ I am only getting stuck on these "source not found" issues during debugging, not during a regular run.  My app is having a FATAL EXCEPTION farther along in the execution. So my thinking is that the SOURCE NOT FOUND errors may not be causing my FATAL EXCEPTIONS.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I added appengine sdk and some other sources, and that destroyed my ADT :-(

I saw that for android-16 and android-17, the platform libraries downloaded by SDK Manager started going to ./sdk/sources whereas prior to my adding appenginge sdk, SDK Manager sent platforms to ./sdk/platforms.

It looks like the change is as a result of the appengine sdk, but for ADT, platform APIs should def be going to ./sdk/platforms

The path ./sdk/sources seems like a more generic java location and is probably the 'correct' path.  Thus Android, as usual, is the problem.  I was pretty sure from this point forward, I would need both ./sdk/sources and ./sdk/platforms, depending on what I was compiling.

So, I moved everything from ./sdk/sources to ./sdk/platform, deleted ./sdk/sources and then created a link 'cd sdk && ln -s platform sources'

Everything works now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution which worked was the answer of [fsbmain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031464/1387524). Kudos to him. I can't comment on his solution because of my low reputation counter. But I want to share my knowledge ;)

I'm working on windows and don't wanted to copy the whole source tree to another location. And copy again on updates etc. So I used the possibility to insert a symbolic link which works since Windows Vista like a charm (or like Linux). For Linux you have to look at the Joe's comment under fsbmain's answer.

Assuming you have the platform in **D:\sdk\platforms\android-19**. Now you have to make a subdirectory **sources** and after that create a relative link to the real sources folder.

```
D:\sdk\platforms\android-19>mkdir sources
D:\sdk\platforms\android-19>cd sources
D:\sdk\platforms\android-19\sources>mklink /D android-19 ..\..\..\sources\android-19
```

Now restart Eclipse ... Done!