# Android Eclipse: Class File Editor - Source not found

Tags: android

i am working on Android project using Eclipse

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

so when i try to debug the code after few step over (f6) the code i get this windows and after that it does not do anything... what should i do to fix this? anybody?

[image]

Comment: please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753021/how-to-attach-source-to-android-jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an error.

FutureTask.java is not your code and actually included in some third party library (or in other project). You only has the .class inside the jar.

Since it's not your code, i believe you should not really need to debug in this FutureTask level. You can just do a step up.

However if you **insist** to debug it, you should attach the project/source code where the FutureTask is located by clicking "Change Attached Source..." If it's a third party, usually there is a source project in the same place you download the jar. If it's your other project, just point the source to your other project.

Comment: not sure where does that FutureTask.java coming from and i am debuggin on my code and as soon as it hits the error it just redirect me to the above screen which is Class File Editor.

Comment: FutureTask is actually inside java.util.concurrent ( means it's a JDK source code ). So you have gone to JDK level. So just ignore this thing and do a step up until you go back to your code level. If you think you really need to debug this FutureTask, you can follow the link provided by idiottiger.

Comment: is there any way to access a .java file from .class file?

Comment: If you want to read the java code of futureTask, you could import the sdk source code to your ide. See idiottiger comment.

Answer (score 0):

FutureTask.java is part of the java.util.concurrent namespace. It's part of Java itself. If you install the java source you'll be able to step into it but normally you wouldn't want to do that.

There's an option under Eclipse's preferences (under Java->Debug->Step Filtering) where you can specify classes Eclipse should not step into.