# Change Attached Source

Tags: android

I have been debugging my android project but when i am trying to step into a braekpoint then a screen comes which says  **SOURCE NOT FOUND** ....plz suggest a solution..i have seen previous suggestions but those didnt work....there is an option provided-- **CHANGE ATTACHED SOURCE**.. which source i have to provide?? i am providing the link for the video..it is ellaborated in the video..plz help...thanks in advance for ur answers
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_I2kWyZePW6VnhOLUxjTFhpTk0/edit?usp=sharing

this is what the log cat says:

```
04-15 11:15:02.380: D/AndroidRuntime(379): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
04-15 11:15:02.380: D/AndroidRuntime(379): CheckJNI is ON
04-15 11:15:02.490: D/AndroidRuntime(379): --- registering native functions ---
04-15 11:15:03.250: D/dalvikvm(284): GC_EXPLICIT freed 523 objects / 29592 bytes in 131ms
04-15 11:15:03.490: D/PackageParser(59): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl55176.tmp
04-15 11:15:03.960: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 18707 objects / 974816 bytes in 89ms
04-15 11:15:04.030: I/PackageManager(59): Removing non-system package:com.drugindexx.demo
04-15 11:15:04.030: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.drugindexx.demo uid=10040
04-15 11:15:04.030: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 362 SIG: 9
04-15 11:15:04.050: W/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain          of:     com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4507a590
04-15 11:15:04.440: D/PackageManager(59): Scanning package com.drugindexx.demo
04-15 11:15:04.440: I/PackageManager(59): Package com.drugindexx.demo codePath changed              from /data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-1.apk to /data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-    2.apk; Retaining data and using new
04-15 11:15:04.450: I/PackageManager(59): /data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-2.apk changed; unpacking
04-15 11:15:04.471: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-2.apk' ---
04-15 11:15:04.820: D/dalvikvm(386): DexOpt: load 42ms, verify 205ms, opt 7ms
04-15 11:15:04.830: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-2.apk'   (success) ---
04-15 11:15:04.830: W/PackageManager(59): Code path for pkg : com.drugindexx.demo changing    from /data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-1.apk to /data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-2.apk
04-15 11:15:04.830: W/PackageManager(59): Resource path for pkg : com.drugindexx.demo changing from /data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-1.apk to /data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-2.apk
04-15 11:15:04.830: D/PackageManager(59):   Activities: com.drugindexx.demo.jsonparsngactivity   com.drugindexx.demo.LoginPage com.drugindexx.demo.Registration com.drugindexx.demo.UserDetails com.drugindexx.demo.MenuOptions com.drugindexx.demo.SarchIndx com.drugindexx.demo.jsonparsngactivity com.drugindexx.demo.Showdetails com.drugindexx.demo.SmsEx com.drugindexx.demo.Settings com.drugindexx.demo.AdvancedSearch com.drugindexx.demo.Gmap com.drugindexx.demo.MyItemizedOverlay com.drugindexx.demo.G
04-15 11:15:04.850: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.drugindexx.demo uid=10040
04-15 11:15:04.950: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.drugindexx.demo-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.drugindexx.demo-2.apk@classes.dex
04-15 11:15:04.950: D/PackageManager(59): New package installed in /data/app/com.drugindexx.demo-2.apk
04-15 11:15:05.080: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.drugindexx.demo uid=10040
04-15 11:15:05.140: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 69 objects / 2728 bytes in 50ms
04-15 11:15:05.390: W/RecognitionManagerService(59): no available voice recognition services found
04-15 11:15:05.490: D/dalvikvm(155): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1809 objects / 92640 bytes in 328ms
04-15 11:15:05.710: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8511 objects / 535000 bytes in 199ms
04-15 11:15:05.710: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.drugindexx.demo-1.apk@classes.dex
04-15 11:15:05.710: D/AndroidRuntime(379): Shutting down VM
04-15 11:15:05.741: D/dalvikvm(379): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-15 11:15:05.760: I/dalvikvm(379): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
04-15 11:15:05.760: I/AndroidRuntime(379): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-15 11:15:06.220: D/AndroidRuntime(392): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
04-15 11:15:06.220: D/AndroidRuntime(392): CheckJNI is ON
04-15 11:15:06.330: D/AndroidRuntime(392): --- registering native functions ---
04-15 11:15:06.850: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.drugindexx.demo uid=10040
04-15 11:15:06.850: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.drugindexx.demo/.jsonparsngactivity }
04-15 11:15:06.960: D/AndroidRuntime(392): Shutting down VM
04-15 11:15:06.969: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.drugindexx.demo for activity com.drugindexx.demo/.jsonparsngactivity: pid=398 uid=10040 gids={3003}
04-15 11:15:06.980: D/jdwp(392): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
04-15 11:15:06.980: D/dalvikvm(392): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-15 11:15:07.260: W/ActivityThread(398): Application com.drugindexx.demo is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-15 11:15:07.280: I/System.out(398): Sending WAIT chunk
04-15 11:15:07.290: I/dalvikvm(398): Debugger is active
04-15 11:15:07.310: I/System.out(398): Debugger has connected
04-15 11:15:07.310: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:07.519: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:07.719: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:07.919: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:08.119: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:08.320: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:08.519: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:08.719: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:08.919: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:09.149: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:09.356: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:09.564: I/System.out(398): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-15 11:15:09.772: I/System.out(398): debugger has settled (1408)
04-15 11:15:13.110: W/System.err(398): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 11:15:13.129: W/System.err(398):  at java.net.URI$Helper.parseURI(URI.java:314)
04-15 11:15:13.129: W/System.err(398):  at java.net.URI$Helper.access$100(URI.java:302)
04-15 11:15:13.140: W/System.err(398):  at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:87)
04-15 11:15:13.140: W/System.err(398):  at com.drugindexx.others.JSONParser.getStringContent(JSONParser.java:37)
04-15 11:15:13.140: W/System.err(398):  at com.drugindexx.demo.jsonparsngactivity$FindStoreLocators.doInBackground(jsonparsngactivity.java:237)
04-15 11:15:13.150: W/System.err(398):  at com.drugindexx.demo.jsonparsngactivity$FindStoreLocators.doInBackground(jsonparsngactivity.java:1)
04-15 11:15:13.150: W/System.err(398):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-15 11:15:13.160: W/System.err(398):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-15 11:15:13.170: W/System.err(398):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-15 11:15:13.170: W/System.err(398):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-15 11:15:13.181: W/System.err(398):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-15 11:15:13.181: W/System.err(398):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-15 11:15:16.922: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-15 11:15:17.221: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44eb0d10 com.drugindexx.demo/.jsonparsngactivity}
04-15 11:15:22.391: D/dalvikvm(284): GC_EXPLICIT freed 216 objects / 14432 bytes in 106ms
04-15 11:15:27.490: D/dalvikvm(295): GC_EXPLICIT freed 848 objects / 58536 bytes in 148ms
04-15 11:15:32.220: D/dalvikvm(398): threadid=7: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
04-15 11:15:32.500: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
04-15 11:15:32.521: D/dalvikvm(248): GC_EXPLICIT freed 317 objects / 17472 bytes in 135ms
04-15 11:15:37.489: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 784 objects / 44784 bytes in 48ms
04-15 11:17:27.744: D/dalvikvm(398): threadid=7: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
```

Comment: check your log cat!!!

Comment: are you trying to debug android sources?..

Comment: yes i m trying to debug my android sources @NickolaiAstashonok

Comment: can u plz elaborate....i.e. what to  check in the log cat??@RobinHood

Comment: Ok, this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753021/how-to-attach-source-to-android-jar/7820622#7820622

Comment: @RobinHood....i have attached the log cat details...kindly check dat

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to debug android sources.

And if you want to do that you need to attach the sources check out :
http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/

But be aware: It's very unlikely that you are really needed to debug the sources, because more likely you did something wrong (Exception) BEFORE the "class not found..." Window pops up.