# Eclipse Java Debug with missing source files

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is there a way to skip the files automatically for which there is no source code in Eclipse while debugging a Java/Android application? So, to be clear, Step Into or Step Over to not display the useless missing file "summary" but to go on until an instruction from my code is reached. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Step Filtering to achieve much the same thing.

Open Java->Debug->Step Filtering in your Eclipse Preferences and add the filters for the classes/packages you have no source for.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Now I only wish I could remove the "Source not found. Edit source lookup path." blank page for the stuff in the Dalvik / Android OS stuff that appears after an unhandled exception.

Comment: Cool. If it's Android source you're missing then maybe check out this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse.

Comment: I'm getting the "do androids dream of electric sheep" reference while trying to access the git repos and the eclipse plugin doesn't work on Helios/Android 3.0 for some reason. In any case, this should not be necessary, I mean one would frequently get 3rd libraries without their source code, not stepping into them should be the default, not require one more click, key press per "Step Into" operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way you can do that. But you can use breakpoints to make larger steps in your code and, that will step over and out of files with no source code.
Just right-click on a line and press "toggle breakpoint".. Hope this helps?