# Android debugger in Eclipse IDE is not working properly

Tags: android

when i proceed step by step debugging I got following things.

Activity.class

Class File Editor

Source not found

The JAR file E:\eclipse\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\android.jar has no sourse attachment.

But i have android.jar in the specified location

This is the one i got while debugging.

My using Win 7 home basic 32-bit, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Indigo Release, Android sdk upto 1.6_r1

Can any one help me....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the android source to eclipse - there's a guide here ( : http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

Also according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse) there are a few other ways too (it look slike the plugin isn't being updated anymore, but http://johnsenf.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-sources-in-eclipse.html looks good)

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to debug into android code? normally we step out/return of it(F7) and do step by step(step over) debugging for our code only..