# How to navigate through Android class files (with source code attached) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class

Usually, I use F3 shortcut to navigate to a variable/method's definition in a project.

For an Android project, sometimes I want to navigate to a class defined in Android SDK, say Activity, the Eclipse will open the class file for me since I attached the source code of Android. However, it stops there, I couldn't use F3 to navigate in the Android class file.

Anyone know how to navigate through the class file? Or any other way that allows me to dig into the source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to attach Android Source to Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse)

Answer (score 6):

Edit: oops, I misunderstood you. Try browsing the source directory mentioned below.

I did it this way:

1. open the `Android SDK Manager`
2. download the `Sources for Android SDK` package for your API level
3. in Eclipse open the properties of your project
4. navigate to `Java Build Path`
5. open the `Libraries` tab
6. unfold the `Android [version number here]` item
7. unfold `android.jar` in there
8. click `Source attachement`
9. hit the `Edit` button
10. in the new window select `External location`
11. hit the `External Folder...` button
12. find the `android-sdk-[your OS here]/sources/android-[API level here]` folder. The `Android SDK Manager` is in `android-sdk-[OS]/tools` if that helps you.
13. hit `OK` until all windows are closed.
14. you should see source code now when hitting `F3`

Based on Eclipse 4.2 Juno, in case you use a different version, names & location can be different.

Answer (score 0):

You have two Ways 1. Attach source for the files that you are trying to look out, in this case download android source and attache it to the eclipse . 2 alternatively you can install decompiller and that will decompile from the class files ( it might not be actual source but indicative ) (search for JAD in case you want to use decompiler method )

Answer (score 0):

I've used the **Android Sources** plugin available from http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/ (scroll down the page to the section **Android Sources**). It automatically attaches source code to the ADT libraries for all Android projects in your workspace.