# How can I navigate to a .java file instead of a .class file with sourcepath specified in the classpath?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classpath

I have a prebuilt jar under my project's libs folder to speed up build-time.  However, I would like to browse the lib's source when navigating into one of its contained classes, so thus added the following line to .classpath:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/mylib.jar" sourcepath="/MyLibSrc"/>
```

Where MyLibSrc contains the source for mylib.jar.  When I navigate into one of the lib's classes, Eclipse opens the corresponding .class file instead of the .java file.  How can I set to open the .java file under MyLibSrc?  There are times when I may actually want to edit the .java file when navigating to it.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/12115117/995891 starting at point 3

Comment: Thanks zapl; I tried it but it still navigates to the .class.

Comment: You can also include the sourcecode into your jar somehow. Maybe that works or is required for `sourcepath` to work.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just right click on your project, go to properties and under source tab in java build path add your Java files of your Jar.. Should work like that.. try both the options.. forgot which one used to work.. did it long back.. all the best

Comment: I think this will force a build of those source files, though, right?  How can I prevent them from building?