# Force JAVA project to use .java files instead of JRE lib .class files (with Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I use **javamail librairy** (developed by Oracle) and I have some issues.

When I call the project with **source or run the .jar** (*java –jar mail.jar*) on **local or on the server** (running on AIX Version 7.1, java version "1.6.0"), it’s ok I receive the mail.

But when I’m calling the .jar with a program (both on the server), the mail sending stops. So I try to **debug the javamail library** (with source) to understand why it stops.

To remote debug java with Eclipse I use:
*java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y -jar /users/java/mail.jar*
http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html

...

My first problem is that **the .jar stop** at: *me = InetAddress.getLocalHost();* in *InternetAdress* class, with no error message.

...

My second problem is when I try to go in the *InetAdress* class and add a *System.out.println*, **the .jar doesn’t pass through this class**. At least not mine: it uses the JRE System Library class (so the println is not use).

I tried to change the JDK project from 1.8 to 1.5;
tried to organise Build Path (with Order and Export option, adding java.net library and put it in top or down);
tried to delete rt.jar from jre lib folder;

Nothing changes…

I found somes questions for my second problem, but it didn’t help me that much:

https://community.oracle.com/message/12729913

[How can I navigate to a .java file instead of a .class file with sourcepath specified in the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203584/how-can-i-navigate-to-a-java-file-instead-of-a-class-file-with-sourcepath-spec)

...

**So how to force JAVA project to use .java files instead of JRE lib .class files with Eclipse ?**

...

*Source of javamail:*
https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home
https://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads?page=1&path%5B%5D=source&theme=java.net

*Source of JDK (to complete with javamail source):*
http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/

Comment: Why do you want to add a ``System.out.println`` ? You can view variable value with debugger.

Comment: I want to add System.out.println because I can't debug when I call the .jar with the program.
I should call the .jar with debug options (with the program) but I can't.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't debug" ? Have you place stoppoint where you suspect anomaly to occurs ?

Comment: As I said, I am able to debug directly when I call the .jar on the server (with debug command lines and Eclipse options), but I can't change how the server program call the .jar, neither say to Eclipse "debug this complied .jar called by this program".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see source file while debugging for libraries, you should attach source to JAR file. In eclipse there are many ways to do it, some of them you can check it here

- 1. Select any Java project
  2. Expand Referenced libraries
  3. Select any JAR file, in our case rt.jar which is Java runtime
  4. Right click and go to properties
  5. Attach source code by browsing source path

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-attach-source-in-eclipse-Jar-JDK-debugging.html#ixzz4ArDVQsub

you should also ensure that both JAR and source version should match, best is to download JAR and source from Maven repository.

Comment: Working fine, I can now debug the JRE System Library using remote debug.

But I still can't debug the .jar using the server program, which stops as I said at **`me = InetAddress.getLocalHost();`** in **`InternetAdress`** class with no error message ! (and working fine when I call the .jar using debug remote...)

Any ideas ?