# Android JAR attach source error

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]I can seem to get rid of this message in eclipse. I am trying to create a simple hello world android app I keep running into the following for the Class File Editor. Side note: I've downloaded and installed the ADT debugger plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not affect your ability to compile and run your apps.

All the source does is show the actual code that is in the jar as well as any documentation it comes with. The only time "Source not found" would come up is if you click on a method that is from the android jar to see more details (such as pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + then clicking "Open Declaration/Implementation").

You should be able to close the Class File Editor that shows this error and continue on with development. If you do want to have the sources available in eclipse [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse) SO question has a few methods.