# Using ADT and SDK manager, attach android source code to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

After installing ADT, I used SDK Manager to download the source codes for the latest android API. Now when I run the Eclipse version that was provided with the ADT, I still can't see the android source codes.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse)

Comment: I saw that one but it refers to a separate plugin for the sources not the android SDK Manager. I just thought it would be automatic if use use the ADT...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open SDK Manager-->install source under api(i.e Android 4.0)

if You got No sources attached then click the button, then choose the Directory

e.g: D:\Android\android___sdk\sources\android-17\  ---> this my android sdk location

Depend upon your android installation directory choose accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

After downloading the Sourcecode by useing the "Android SDK Manager", you have to change the settings in your eclipse-porject.

At first, just have a look where the Sourcecode has been downloaded. In my case (useing Windows 8) its here:
"C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\sources\android-17"

- Now go into Eclipse.
- Open the "Properties" of the project (right click on the project-folder and click on "Properties").
- On the left side click on "Java Build Path" and then click on the tab-page "Libraries".
- Next you click on the right side on the button "Add External Class Folder...".
- Select the folder where you find the sourcecode. In my case its the folder "android-17" of the path "C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\sources\android-17".
- Commit / close all windows with ok. (Maybe you should restart eclipse.)

And now you can see/read the Android-Sourcecode. (But only in the project which you have choosen before.)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to download them. Use Android SDK Manager -> Android X.Y.Z (API A) -> Sources for Android SDK.

Then, you need to attach the folder with the sources the next time you browse there: /sources/android-A

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are great but [here you have a complete resource by Lars Vogel who address this question](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/01/10/making-the-android-sdk-source-code-available-in-eclipse/). I hope it may be useful as well as it was for me.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found this for me:

For main lib: android.jar:
src: sdk/sources/android-19
doc: sdk/docs/reference/

For support lib: android-support-v4.jar:
(before this we should add android-support-v4.jar like external jar (Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries, then in Tab ‘Order and Export’ pull up this library before Android Private Libraries))
src: sdk/extras/android/support/v4/src/java
doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html (not sure)