# How to find the sources of Android Private Libraries

Tags: java, android

I want to see the sources of the libraries in directory: Android Private Libraries. When I try to do so it says "Source not found".
Can someone tell me where they are stored?

Comment: "Android Private Libraries" is a label, not a specific library.

Answer (score 0):

The Sources are on sdk\sources

usualy adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\sources

but you can fix it by adding sources to the Project

[Adding Android Sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse)