# Eclipse: attach source for android.R.layout.*

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have already successfully setup Eclipse via 
[How to attach Android Source to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233640/best-way-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse) to show me source for classes. How can I get it to do the same for android.R.*? I always get "Source not found" warning.

For example, I want to be able to jump directly to the XML for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 from code.

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the code.

Comment: I've tried that along with closing/re-opening the project. I think it's related to the fact that the layout files are outside of the path used for source (by default from the SDK manager): `sdk/platforms/android-21` vs `sdk/sources/android-21`