# How do i go to back to Application project from library project in android

Tags: android, android-intent, shared-libraries

---

Hi all
In my application project i used library project. I used bellow code to go from application project to library project. It is working well but my problem is when click back button i am getting error

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("pakagename",packagename.classname"));
intent.putExtra("image",path);
```

How can i go back from library project to application project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what error you are getting??

Comment: Source not found. Error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964620/how-to-find-easily-the-source-of-an-android-class/1965543#1965543   see this..